# Call an imported object from a string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this Vue plugin

```
import Movement from './Movement'

const PolicyCanPlugin = {
    install(Vue, {store}) {
        Vue.prototype.$policyCan = (model, method) => {
            // how can I call Movement.update_user() using the model(Movement) and method(update_user) variables
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call dynamic method from a dynamic model that is already imported (Movement)

I want to call `this.$policyCan('Movement', 'update_user')` and trigger `Movement.update_user()`

Comment: model[method]() will translate to model['update_user'](). Does this help?

Comment: Why not use vuex?

Comment: @ssBarBee calling `Movement['update_user']()` works, but not with the variables `model[method]()`

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren I'm already using vuex, but all my mutations and states are in a store file, can I write another methods without throuing all the methods in my `store.js` file?

Comment: what is the value of model and method? In your comments you said that model is Movement and method is update_user.

Comment: @ssBarBee yes, I debugged with console.log to see if I was passing something wrong, the value of `model` is `'Movement'`, the value of `method` is `'update_user'`,  so `Movement['update_user']` worked, but `model[method]` didn't

Comment: import Movement from './Movement'
export default ({store}) => { 
const PolicyCanPlugin = { 
store // are accessible here
}
So this way you can use your store.state, store.getters ....
}